# The mechanism to use recursion printReverse String

Tags: python, algorithm

I am reading [Explore - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/recursion-i/250/principle-of-recursion/1439/).

It illustrate recursion with a simple but trick example `printReverse`

> Let's start with a simple programming problem:
>
> > Print a string in reverse order.
>
> You can easily solve this problem iteratively, *i.e.* looping through the string starting from its last character. But how about solving it recursively?
>
> First, we can define the desired function as `printReverse(str[0...n-1])`, where `str[0]` represents the first character in the string. Then we can accomplish the given task in two steps:
>
> 1. `printReverse(str[1...n-1])`: print the substring `str[1...n-1]` in reverse order.
> 2. `print(str[0])`: print the first character in the string.
>
> Notice that we call the function itself in the first step, which by definition makes the function recursive.

The implementation

```
import unittest
import logging 
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(levelname)s %(message)s")

def printReverse(s):
    helper(0, s)

def helper(idx, s):
    if s == None or idx >= len(s):
        return 
    logging.debug(f"index:{idx}")
    helper(idx+1, s)
    print(s[idx])

class MyCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_printReverse(self):
        s = 'string'
        printReverse(s)

unittest.main()
```

I am very confused with how it works. especially the first  s[0] is not s but g.

```
$ python printReverse.py 
DEBUG index:0
DEBUG index:1
DEBUG index:2
DEBUG index:3
DEBUG index:4
DEBUG index:5
g
n
i
r
t
s
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

I am acknowledged that a calling stack is executing as

```
def printReverse2(s):
    stack = []
    for c in s:
        stack.append(c)
    for c in stack:
        print(c)
```

However, the process is implicit, seems that there is not such step to put all characters to stack but instantly jump to `for c in stack, print(c)`

How could design a debugging to see the process of producing a calling stack?
.

Comment: It's not `for c in stack`, it's more like `while c=stack.pop()`. Items are popped off the stack in LIFO order (last in, first out). In other words, in reverse.

Comment: And the part of the code that puts all characters to the stack is the recursive call (`helper(idx+1, s)`).

Comment: yes, got it `while c =stack.pop()` is smart and of PEP 572 style. @Blorgbeard

Comment: Now, I am clear that is stuck to understand the stack process of  the tail recursion `helper(idx+1, s)` @Blorgbeard

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question - can you be more explicit?

Comment: How could see the process when helper push each character to stack @Blorgbeard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `printReverse('string')` which calls `helper(0, 'string')`. And that's fine and clear.

But how do we get the result? The `print(s[idx])` line should print `s` - the first character, right? But wait, the Python interpreter has to execute the previous line which is `helper(idx+1, s)` first.

Executing that statement means that Python has to pop the result value of that execution (in your case, helper doesn't return anything i.e. None) and in fact for each of `t, r, i, n, g` there's a new stack frame. How does that look like?

1. You call the helper with `helper(0, 'string')`
2. `helper(0, 'string')` frame waits for the result of `helper(1, 'string')` before it prints `'string'[0]'` which is `s`.
3. `helper(1, 'string')` frame waits for the result of `helper(2, 'string')` before it prints `'string'[1]'` which is `t`
4. ...
5. `helper(5, 'string')` waits for the result of `helper(6, 'string')`
6. `helper(6, 'string')` is a little bit different since `6 >= len('string')`. The `if` is triggered, and it has a result `None` - it doesn't have to wait for anything!
7. Now `helper(5, 'string')` has the result of `helper(6, 'string')` and proceeds to the `print` statement. The last character `g` appears on the screen.
8. `helper(4, 'string')` has the result of `helper(5, 'string')` and can proceed to the print statement and you get a `n`.
9. ... And so on
10. ...Until you have the result of `helper(1, 'string')` and the original call `helper(0, 'string')` can print `s`.

You can use the [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)  module to pause your Python program and execute it line-by-line.

Comment: appreciate for your detailed explanation, Brilliant .You cannot imagine how happy I am now. lol